# Code using async/await fails when an HttpClient request is sent

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, asynchronous, async-await

I have a WinForms application that has two roles. If no command line parameters are present, the Main function calls Application.Run, and presents the UI. If command line parameters are present, Application.Run is NOT called. Instead, I call an async method like this:

```
result = HandleCommandLine(args).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

(I am new to async/await, and this form was based on a SO answer).

The end goal is to loop through a list, and for each entry, start a new task. Each of those tasks should run in parallel with the others. The tasks are started like this:

```
runningTasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew((args) => HandlePlayback( (Dictionary<string,string>) ((object[])args)[0]), new object[] { runArgs } ));
```

The tasks are added to the collection of runningTasks, and I later call:

```
Task.WaitAll(runningTasks.ToArray());
```

In each of the runningTasks, I am trying to send web requests using HttpClient:

```
using (HttpResponseMessage response = await Client.SendAsync(message))
{
    using (HttpContent responseContent = response.Content)
    {
        result = await responseContent.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
}
```

Once Client.SendAsync is called, the whole thing goes belly up. All of my runningTasks complete, and the application exits. Nothing past the Client.SendAsync executes in any of those tasks.

Since I am new at async/await, I have very few ideas about what *exactly* might be wrong, and hence few ideas about how to fix it. I imagine it has something to do with the SynchronizationContexts in this situation (WinForms app acting like a console app), but I'm not grasping what I need to do and where to keep the service request and the web request async calls from causing everything to complete too early.

I guess my question then is, why are (only some) 'awaited' calls causing all tasks to complete? What can I do about it?

**UPDATE:**

Two things. @Joe White: The WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext.Current is always null wherever I check.

@David Pine: Minimal (kind of :) ) complete viable example follows. You will either need to add a command line argument to the project, or force execution to the HandleCommandLine function. In this example, it tries to make a website request for each of three sites. It doesn't appear to matter if they exist. The code reaches the Client.SendAsync some number of times (usually not three), but timing appears to matter.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    static class Program
    {
        static List<Task> runningTasks = new List<Task>();

        [STAThread]
        static int Main()
        {
            int result = 1; // true, optimism

            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

            string[] args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();

            if (args.Length > 1)
            {
                // do the command line work async, while keeping this thread active
                result = HandleCommandLine(args).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            }
            else
            {
                // normal interface mode
                Application.Run(new Form1());
            }

            return result;
        }


        static async Task<int> HandleCommandLine(string[] args)
        {
            // headless mode

            int result = 1; // true, optimism

            result = await HandleControlMode(args);


            return result;
        }

        private static async Task<int> HandleControlMode(string[] Arguments)
        {
            int result = 1; // optimism

            try
            {
                List<string> sites = new List<string>() { @"http://localhost/site1", @"http://localhost/site2", @"http://localhost/site3" };
                foreach (string site in sites)
                {
                    Begin(site);    // fire off tasks

                    // the HandleControlMode method is async because in other circumstances, I do the following:
                    //await Task.Delay(5000); // sleep 5 seconds

                }

                // wait while all test running threads complete
                try
                {
                    Task.WaitAll(runningTasks.ToArray());
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    // not really a catch all handler...
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                // not really a catch all handler...
            }

            return result;

        }

        private static void Begin(string site)
        {
            //runningTasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() => HandlePlayback(runArgs)));
            runningTasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew((args) => HandlePlayback((string)((object[])args)[0]), new object[] { site }));
        }

        private static async Task<int> HandlePlayback(string site)
        {
            int result = 1;

            try
            {
                PlaybackEngine engine = new PlaybackEngine(site);
                bool runResult = await engine.RunCommandLine(site);

                if (!runResult)
                {
                    result = 0;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                result = 0;
            }

            return result;
        }
    }

    public class PlaybackEngine
    {
        private static HttpClientHandler ClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler()
        {
            AllowAutoRedirect = false,
            AutomaticDecompression = System.Net.DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate
        };
        private static HttpClient Client = new HttpClient(ClientHandler);

        public string Target { get; set; }

        public PlaybackEngine(string target)
        {
            Target = target;
        }

        public async Task<bool> RunCommandLine(string site)
        {
            bool success = true;
            string response = await this.SendRequest();
            return success;
        }

        private async Task<string> SendRequest()
        {
            string result = string.Empty;

            string requestTarget = Target;

            HttpMethod method = HttpMethod.Post;
            var message = new HttpRequestMessage(method, requestTarget);

            StringContent requestContent = null;
            requestContent = new StringContent("dummycontent", Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

            message.Content = requestContent;

            try
            {
                using (HttpResponseMessage response = await Client.SendAsync(message))
                {
                    using (HttpContent responseContent = response.Content)
                    {
                        result = await responseContent.ReadAsStringAsync();
                        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(result);
                    }
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }

            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE2:**
I put similar code online at http://rextester.com/CJS33330

It's a straight console app, and I've added .ConfigureAwait(false) to all awaits (with no effect). In separate testing, I tried 4 or 5 other ways to call the first async function from Main - which all worked but had the same behavior.

Comment: I wonder if your WinForms dependencies are somehow causing your code to run with the WinForms SynchronizationContext (which would be bad, since your main thread isn't pumping messages - instead it's blocking). Could you check what `SynchronizationContext.Current` is, and more interestingly, what type it is when your application is running?

Comment: Not related, but for web services requests you don't need to start own task. That is one of the `async-await` benefit - accessing of external resource can be done on one thread without blocking main application.

Comment: @Fabio: I am not looking at my code to remember for sure, but I believe I ended up with the web service call returning a task because it was driven by other async calls in the web service code. Rather than solving the problem of having the service code be async, but the service interface not be async, I just left it that way. That code is also used when the UI is running, and it seemed to work fine there. It's only now that I am trying to run these tasks in parallel that it's causing an issue. I will double check tomorrow at work if I can get the async out of the service interface.

Comment: @Joe White: I will take a look when I get back to work and see what I can learn about the SynchronizationContext.

Comment: There are a ton of details, almost too many. And the actual issue seems very unlikely - I propose that you supply a minimal, complete and viable example so we can actually try to help https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: @David Pine: I removed some details, and restricted the question to match the example I have now provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with this code is that I am not waiting on the Tasks that I thought I was. The runningTasks collection accepts any kind of Task. I didn't realize that Task.Factory.StartNew returned different type than the Task I was trying to start. My function returns

```
Task<int>
```

but StartNew returns

```
Task<Task<int>>
```

Those tasks completed immediately, and so the main thread did not stay alive long enough for the actual routines to run. You have to wait on the inner task instead:

```
Task<Task<int>> wrappedTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(...);
Task<int> t = await wrappedTask;
runningTasks.Add(t);

...

Task allTasks = Task.WhenAll(runningTasks.ToArray());
await allTasks;
```

For some reason, I was not able to use the built in ".Unwrap" function that should be equivalent, but the above code does the job.